# Unable to play HD video using vlc

Tags: pi-3b+, video, vlc, yocto

I buid an image for Raspberry pi 3b+ using yocto project. While building it I have used VLC instead of OMXplayer for playing videos, and enabled the hardware acceleration using  `--enable-omxil --enable-omxil-vout --enable-rpi-omxil --enable-mmal`
But the problem is with the 1080x1920 resolution videos. VLC is not able to play these videos. I used `--codec omxil --vout omxil_vout` while playing the video, but it still showing avcodec as decoder and video is getting stucked.

Comment: might be insufficient computing power if it only happens on high res

Comment: What format is the video file you are trying to play and is it stored locally on the Pi?

Comment: format is .h264, yes it is stored locally in pi, and i am able to play the same video using omxplayer

Comment: what happens if you play the video in vlc without any options

Comment: same problem, it stucks with the same avcodec decoder error. Basically as far as I understand it is not able to use omxil for the hardware acceleration